# Angular/npm: Create one project from another

Tags: angular

I've got a Angular project (with logging, authorization, shared components, navigation etc. etc.) and I would like to use this project as a template for other projects. It also contains a few project-specific modules that would need to be removed. But other modules can be reuse by other projects.

Sure I can copy it, remove the modules, adapt the app.module and the index.html. But I'm wondering, is there some kind of a automatism available?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in the end you will have multiple apps with shared libraries (modules). Then let's have a look at monorepos, e.g. https://nx.dev/. You can create one workspace with multiple independent apps and shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options available:

1. Using a monorepo structure for your projects with something like [nx](https://nx.dev/)
2. Creating your own Angular [schematic](https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring)